# Showing a simple determinant property

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant

I want to use Laplace expansion to show/prove to myself formally that the rule for determinants stating that if B is a matrix obtained from A , where $A \in \mathbb M_{nxn}$, by multiplying a row or column of A by some scalar $\lambda$ then this implies $|B|=\lambda |A|$ (referring to determinant).

Il write what I have\know,

denote $A=[a_{ij}]$

from laplace expansion, we know that $|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n}$ $a_{ij}(-1)^{i+j}|\mathbb M_{ij}|$ for any row i $\in \{1,…,n\}$ Where $\mathbb M_{ij}$ represents the minor of the element $a_{ij}$

Im thinking I could maybe do something like, suppose we are expanding on row i, and we multiply every element in i by \lambda to obtain some matrix B

then we would have $|B|= \lambda a_{ij}(-1)^{i+1}+…+\lambda a_{in}(-1)^{i+n}$

But $\lambda$ is just a scalar so we can write $|B|=\lambda( a_{ij}(-1)^{i+1}+…+ a_{in}(-1)^{i+n})$ = $\lambda |A|$

However, I am not sure if what I am thinking is valid, or makes sense. I am open to any comments/critiques/suggestions etc, thanks!

Comment: The determinant is multiplied by λ$^n$.

Comment: Sorry I meant multiplying a row or column il edit

Comment: The style is a bit non-mathematical but the concept is fine

Comment: I'll withdraw my comment since it's corrected. But it's simpler to say the reason is multilinearity of the determinant w.r.t. rows or columns. However this may depend on the definition of determinants you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is correct. More succinctly, let $B$ be equal to $A$ with $\lambda$ multiplied to row $i$, and expand about row $i$ to get:
\begin{align}
\det(B) 
&= \sum_{j} (-1)^{i+j}b_{ij}\det(\mathbb{M}_{ij})\\
&= \sum_{j} (-1)^{i+j}\lambda a_{ij}\det(\mathbb{M}_{ij})\\
&= \lambda\sum_{j} (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}\det(\mathbb{M}_{ij})\\
&= \lambda \det(A)
\end{align}
As an aside, you can also use the formula for the determinant based on the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Applications_and_examples):
\begin{align} 
\det(B) 
&= \sum_{j_1}\cdots\sum_{j_n}\varepsilon_{j_1,\ldots,j_n}\prod_k b_{kj_k}\\ 
&= \sum_{j_1}\cdots\sum_{j_n}\varepsilon_{j_1,\ldots,j_n} b_{ij_i}\prod_{k\ne i} b_{kj_k}\\
&= \sum_{j_1}\cdots\sum_{j_n}\varepsilon_{j_1,\ldots,j_n} \lambda a_{ij_i}\prod_{k\ne i} a_{kj_k}\\
&=  \lambda\sum_{j_1}\cdots\sum_{j_n}\varepsilon_{j_1,\ldots,j_n} a_{ij_i}\prod_{k\ne i} a_{kj_k}\\ &= \lambda\det(A)
\end{align}
(e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815278/determinant-with-levi-civita-symbol)).